# Drilling in the wall, encountered metal too soon

Tags: walls, drill, hole

I was trying to mount a tv support in the wall that separates the kitchen from the living room (from the living room side, and do note that the sink and the stove are on another wall, parallel to this one).

I checked with the Bosch gms120 that there wasn't anything wrong. It was yellow-ish, meaning that there could be metal traces or metal deep down in the wall. However, since I didn't need to drill very deep, I proceeded.

After a few millimeters, the drill started sounding like it hit some metal thing, so I stopped and checked.

Double checked with the detector, and still yellow, like there is almost nothing.

What is that thing in the wall? The whole area around it (in a 15 cm radius) is yellow, with some parts in red far from where I drilled.[image]

EDIT: Yellow and red are the colours displayed by the detector for "there may be some metal deep down" and "there is metal close, do not drill here". I live in Sweden, forgot to mention. The wallpaper is fibrous, not the wall, that seems to me concrete. On the other side of the wall there shouldn't be anything, I can't check since there is heavy furniture covering the wall in that spot.

Comment: 1: Where in Planet Earth are you - country wise ? 2: Your picture is not representing your wording - yellow and red I do not see. 3: The wall looks like it is fibrous ? House in USA : Metal Studs or Metal Barrier to protect wiring .. any outlets nearby on either side of the wall where you are drilling ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a magnet to identify the outline of the metal.

It could easily be a nail plate:
[image: Nail Plate]

The purpose of which is to protect wires and pipes, from you.